# What is this usb property

Tags: usb

I stumbled upon property "ro.usb.vid=2970" so anyone know what it means and where it gets stored in which file because it's not in build.prop or default.prop..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A USB device has a Vendor ID and a Product ID for the host to distinguish a device model. Both are 2-bytes integer. That `ro.usb.vid` is exactly your device's USB VID. It is located at

```
/sys/class/android_usb/android0/idVendor
```

Use `cat` in a terminal to read its value and `echo` to change it (effective until next boot).
Also you can find your device's USB PID at

```
/sys/class/android_usb/android0/idProduct
```

which is likely named `ro.usb.pid` in the same place. Again use `cat` and `echo` to access it.